# Django - How to efficiently add a list to a many-to-many model field

Tags: python, django

I have three models. Posts, Tags and Subscribers. There is a many-to-many relationship between Posts and Subscribers and another many-to-many relationship between Tags and Subscribers. There is a ForeignKey relationship between Posts and Tags. I want to add all the subscribers for a given post to it's associated tag. I am able to achieve this by doing the following. But is there a more efficient way to do this than to iterate through two for loops ?

```
all_subscribers = post.subscribers.all()
for tag in tags:
    for subscriber in all_subscribers:
        tag.subscriber.add(subscriber)
tag.save()
```

Please note that I am using a toy example above for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
for tag in tags:
    tag.subscriber.add(*all_subscribers)
    tag.save()
```

Another way, and a faster one, is to create the intermediate table

```
class Subscription(models.Molde):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber)
```

And then bulk create the subscriptions

```
subscriptions = []
for tag in tags:
    for subscriber in all_subscribers:
        subscriptions.append(Subscription(tag=tag, subscriber=subscriber))
Subscription.objects.bulk_create(subscriptions)
```